Strengthen the claim on the behavior of a holomorphic function near its zero
Let $U$ be a non-empty, open and connected set in complex plane, i.e. a domain. Consider a non-constant holomorphic function $f: U\to \mathbb{C}$ and suppose $a\in U$ is a zero of $f$ with order $n$. Standard textbooks on complex analysis usually tell us about the behavior of $f$ near $a$ as follows:
Theorem. We can find an open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $a$, such that $W = f(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $0= f(a)$. Furthermore, every fiber $f^{-1}(w)\cap V$ with $w\in W\setminus\{0\}$ has exactly $n$ elements.
This property is beautiful. However, it seems to deserve a stronger claim. Is it possible that we can always choose $V$ carefully, in order that $V$ (and consequently, $W$) is connected?

That is true. There is a open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ and an injective function $h: U \to \Bbb C$ such that $h(a) = 0$ and $f(z) = h(z)^n$ for all $z \in U$. Now we can choose a disk $W = B_r(0) \subset h(U)$ and $V' = h^{-1}(W)$. Then both $V'$ and $W$ are connected (in fact: simply connected), and $f(z) = h(z)^n$ for all $z \in W$, so that every $w\in W\setminus\{0\}$ has exactly $n$ preimages in $V'$.

Understood. To reach the result as I state above, there are two different ways. One is by the principle of argument and the other one is constructing a n-th root function. The latter is somewhat harder. (To construct root function elegantly requires knowledge about covering spaces from algebraic topology.) But as your answer shows, the harder technique unveils deeper structure.
